# How to import a Whatsapp text file into python pandas dataframe4

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just starting off and I'm a beginner and playing around and learning so apologies if this is basic.

I've changed the working directory to pick up the file where it is saved under:

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/MyName/Documents')
print("Current working directory: {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
```

Importing the file here:

```
conversation = 'WhatsApp Chat with AC.txt'
with open(conversation, encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    fp.readline()
    messageBuffer = []
    date, time, author = None, None, None
    while True:
        line = fp.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        line = line.strip()
        if date_time(line):
            if len(messageBuffer) > 0:
                data.append([date, time, author, ' '.join(messageBuffer)])
            messageBuffer.clear()
            date, time, author, message = getDatapoint(line)
            messageBuffer.append(message)
        else:
            messageBuffer.append(line)
```

But when I put a test here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Date", 'Time', 'Author', 'Message'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df.tail(20))
print(df.info())
print(df.Author.unique())
```

An empty dataframe shows up with 0 index entries. Just don't know what I'm missing to pick up the text file.

Comment: Could you provide us with the format of the input file?

Comment: Hi it is just a .txt file